# Presentations: fewer relations than generators implies $G$ infinite.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

[image: Image 1]

Take $r=0$. Let $G=\langle a_1\rangle \times ...\times \langle a_n\rangle, \langle a_i\rangle$ infinite cyclic. $G$ is generated by $n$ elements and all relations in $A$ are relations in $G$. Therefor by von  Dyck's theorem there is an epimorphism from $A$ to $G$. But $G$ is infinite and so, $A$ is infinite too.

For the case $r>0$ I have been unable to find a proof. I don't want a solution. I only ask for a hint which allows me to begin working in the problem.

Comment: As a further hint, try defining a nontrivial homomorphism from $A$ to the infinite cyclic group $\langle t \rangle$. So each $x_i$ is mapped to $t^{n_i}$ for some $n_i \in {\mathbb Z}$ and, to apply von Dyck's theorem, the images must satisfy the relations of $A$. So we end up with a system of $r$ linear equations that the $n_i$ must satisfy.

Comment: I define $\lambda: A\to \langle t\rangle$ in the following way: given $g\in A$ write $g$ in normal form, $g=y_1...y_k$ where $y_i\in X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$. And I write $g\lambda=t^1...t^k$. By the uniqueness of the normal form $\lambda$ is well defined.

Comment: I MADE A MISTAKE. $g$ is in reduced form, $g=y_1^{\epsilon_1},...,y_k^{\epsilon_k}$.             Now, for instance, $(x_2x_5x_2)\lambda=(x_2^2x_5)\lambda=t^4t^5=t^2t^5t^2=(x_2\lambda)(x_5\lambda)(x_2\lambda)$, showing $\lambda$ is a homomorphism. But there is a difficulty. Suppose $x_1x_2=1$ is a relation. Then $t^3=t t^2=(x_1\lambda)(x_2\lambda)= (x_1x_2)lambda=1\lambda=1$ and $t$ has finite order! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Suppose I prove the existence of a homomorphism $\alpha:A\to \langle t\rangle$. Then, for instance, if $x_1^2x_2=1$ in $A$, then $t^{2n_1+n_2}=t^{2n_1}t^n_2=(x_1^2x_2)\alpha=1\alpha=1$. But $t$ has infinite order. Therefor $2n_1+n_2=0$. In this way I end up with a system with less equations than unknowns. Such a system, when the $n_i$ belong to field, has infinitely many solutions. I don't know what happens in a ring (the ring $Z$). Anyway, suppose there are infinitely many solutions in $Z$. The set of all these solutions (n-plas in $Z$) constitute a $Z$-module. What do I do now?

Comment: Once you know that there is a nonzero solution you are done.

Comment: It is a duplicate: I remember answering about 8 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $A$ is an abelian group, so think of it as a $\Bbb Z$-module.  $A$ can be presented as the quotient of $\Bbb Z^n$ by the (free) submodule generated by the $r$ relations.

Comment: The presentation given in the problem is an epimorphism from a free group $F$ onto $A$. You mean $F$ is free abelian?

Comment: Because we already know that $A$ is abelian, we can interpret the setup in the problem as an epimorphism from the free abelian group onto $A$.

Comment: Hum... $A=F/R$ where $R$ is the normal closure of the set consisting in the relations. That $F/R$ is abelian does not mean $F$ is abelian. The relations $[x_i,x_j]=1$ are to be interpreted as $[x_i,x_j]\in R$. Why is $F$ abelian?

Comment: Let $F$ denote the free group on $n$ elements. Define $\tilde F$ to be $F/S$ where $S$ is the normal closure of the relations $[x_i,x_j] = 1$.  $A$ can be presented as $\tilde F/R$, where $R$ is the subgroup of $\tilde F$ generated by the $r$ remaining relations

Comment: I understand, though I can't see the details. $\bar F$ is a presentation of the free abelian group of rank $n$. So, $\bar F$ itself is free abelian. Let $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and $s_1(x),...,s_r(x)$ the  remaining relations. Then $R=\langle s_1(x)S,...,s_r(x)S\rangle$. And $A$ has the presentation $A=\langle X\mid s_1(x)S,...,s_r(x)S\rangle$. Am I right?

Comment: That seems reasonable, but I'm not sure. In any case, as I state in my answer, it is easier and sufficient to think of $A$ as a quotient of $\Bbb Z$-modules.